# how to change pagenav first number to linked to the orginal url of the page thread or post

Tags: php, vbulletin

hi  i need help i have page navigation 
look like this in the page navigation  in vbuilletin 4.1.1:

First Previous ,1 , 2, Next Last

when i click the page 2 the url shows like that :

`http://localhost/vbs/forumdisplay.php?f=2&page=2&order=desc`

and that is fine with me but what i want is when i click 
back to the page number 1 or click the "first" button

i don't want it to show the url like this :

`http://localhost/vbs/forumdisplay.php?f=1&page=2&order=desc`

what i want is to show the original url of 
the first page for the thread or the post like this

`http://localhost/vbs/forumdisplay.php?f=2`

i tried to modify the pagenave template but with no success
plz can anyone advice me what i can do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((int)$_GET['f']<2){
   header('Location: http://localhost/vbs/forumdisplay.php?f=2');
   die();
}
```

put this on top of the page... before any html output.